# Equality between supremum of sums

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $q \in \mathbb{N}$, $q \geq 2$. Assume that for any $k \in \{1, \ldots, q\}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\sup_{z \in \mathbb{C}_+} |f_k(z)| = \sup_{w \in \mathbb{R}} |f_k(iw)|,
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{C}_+ \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{z \in \mathbb{C} \ \colon \ \Re(z)>0\}$ denotes the open right half-plane. The functions $f_k$ are continuous and bounded on the closure of $\mathbb{C}_+$ and are analytic on $\mathbb{C}_+$.

> I am looking for a way to show that
>   \begin{align*}
> \sup_{z \in \mathbb{C}_+} \Big(\sum_{k=1}^q|f_k(z)|^2 \Big) = \sup_{w \in \mathbb{R}} \Big(\sum_{k=1}^q|f_k(iw)|^2\Big).
> \end{align*}

I would be grateful for any hint. I only seem to be able to show that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{z \in \mathbb{C}_+} \Big(\sum_{k=1}^q|f_k(z)|^2 \Big) \leq  \sum_{k=1}^q \sup_{w \in \mathbb{R}} |f_k(iw)|^2,
\end{align*}
or 
\begin{align*}
\sup_{z \in \mathbb{C}_+} \Big(\sum_{k=1}^q|f_k(z)|^2 \Big) \leq q \sup_{w \in \mathbb{R}} \Big(\sum_{k=1}^q|f_k(iw)|^2\Big).
\end{align*}
(using equivalence of the $\infty$-norm and the euclidean norm).